# Google Maps API - Geocoding + Heatmap

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoding-api

I am trying to build an app where I can insert an array with postcodes, do a geocoding API process (which works) in order to transform the postcodes into long/lat, and then create a heatmap using those long/lat combinations (which doesn't work). I have used the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Heatmap</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #floating-panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 25%;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
        line-height: 30px;
        padding-left: 10px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="floating-panel">
      <input id="address" type="textbox" value="Sydney, NSW">
      <input id="submit" type="button" value="Geocode">
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
        function initMap() {
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 8,
                center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644}
            });
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

            geocodeAddress(geocoder, map);
        }

        function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap) {
            // var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
            // 
            var listAddress = [ "AB31", "AB38", "AB41", "AB42", "AB45", "AB51", "AB56", "AL1 ", "AL2 ", "AL3 ", "AL4 ", "AL5 ", "AL7 ", "AL8 ", "APTE", "B13 ", "B14 ", "B15 ", "B17 ", "B25 ", "B27 ", "B28 ", "B29 ", "B30 ", "B44 ", "B46 ", "B47 ", "B49 ", "B60 ", "B62 ", "B63 ", "B72 ", "B73 ", "B74 ", "B75 ", "B77 ", "B78 ", "B79 ", "B90 ", "B91 ", "B92 ", "B93 ", "B94 ", "B95 ", "B96 ", "B97 ", "B98 ", "BA1 ", "BA11", "BA13", "BA14", "BA15", "BA16", "BA2 ", "BA21", "BA22", "BA3 ", "BA4 ", "BA8 ", "BB1 ", "BB10", "BB11", "BB12", "BB18", "BB2 ", "BB3 ", "BB4 ", "BB5 ", "BB6 ", "BB7 ", "BB8 ", "BB9 ", "BD10", "BD11", "BD12", "BD13", "BD14", "BD15", "BD16", "BD17", "BD18", "BD19", "BD2 ", "BD20", "BD21", "BD22", "BD23", "BD24", "BD3 " ];

            for (index = 0; index < listAddress.length; ++index) {
                // console.log(listAddress[index]);

                var address = listAddress[index],
                    loc=[],
                    lat='',
                    lng='',
                    locationEach='';
                    heatmapData = [];

                geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
                  // if (status === 'OK') {
                  //   resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                  //   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  //     map: resultsMap,
                  //     position: results[0].geometry.location
                  //   });
                  // } else {
                  //   alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
                  // }
                  if (status === 'OK') {
                    loc[0]=results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                    loc[1]=results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                    console.log(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
                    lat = String(loc[0]);
                    lng = String(loc[1]);
                    locationEach = lat + ', ' + lng;


                    heatmapData.push( new google.maps.LatLng( locationEach ) );

                    console.log( heatmapData );
                    heatMap(heatmapData);

                  } else {
                    alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
                  }
                });
            }
        }

      // var sanFrancisco = new google.maps.LatLng(37.774546, -122.433523);

      // map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      //   center: sanFrancisco,
      //   zoom: 13,
      //   mapTypeId: 'satellite'
      // });

      function heatMap(heatmapData) {
          var heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
            data: heatmapData,
            setMap: map
          });
          // heatmap.setMap(map);
      }

    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&libraries=visualization&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Ideal result: The array of postcodes would be used to create a heatmap.

#### EDIT:

I have managed to fix the errors in the console but now it is still not showing the heatmap on the map.

Comment: Reason for minus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple issues here:

1. The requests to geocode the points happen asynchronously. Because of this, the heat map needs to be added after all points have been geocoded. One way to do this is to check if the length of *heatmapData* is equal to the length of the array of addresses. So in the callback of **geocoder.geocode()**, add this check:

   ```
   } else {
     alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
   }
   if (heatmapData.length == listAddress.length ) {
     //call heatmap() here
     heatmap()
   }
   ```
2. The variable *map* is visible within the [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope) of **initMap()**, so when the code in function *heatMap()* adds the heatmap, it can't resolve *map*. To avoid that issue, declare *map* before outside of function **initMap()**. See the example below:

   ```
   var map, heatmapData = [];
   function initMap() {
       map = map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    // ...
   }
   function heatMap() {
       //map and heatmapData are now visible
   }
   ```

See these changes demonstrated in [this plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/Ve0QsucLGlG0mULiUVtj/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I just managed to fix those issues. Please check updated code.

Comment: Finally managed to do it thanks! now I need to tackle the limit of requests per second :)